# manipulating LARGE_INTEGERS

Tags: c++, int64

I am converting some code from C to C++ in MS dev studio under win32. In the old code I was doing some high speed timings using QueryPerformanceCounter() and did a few manipulations on the __int64 values obtained, in particular a minus and a divide. But now under C++ I am forced to use LARGE_INTEGER because that's what QueryPerformanceCounter() returns. But now on the lines where I try and do some simple maths on the values I get an error:

error C2676: binary '-' : 'LARGE_INTEGER' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

I tried to cast the variables to __int64 but then get:

error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'LARGE_INTEGER' to '__int64'

How do I resolve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 31, accepted):

LARGE_INTEGER is a union of a 64-bit integer and a pair of 32-bit integers. If you want to perform 64-bit arithmetic on one you need to select the 64-bit int from inside the union.

```
LARGE_INTEGER a = { 0 };
LARGE_INTEGER b = { 0 };

__int64 c = a.QuadPart - b.QuadPart;
```

Comment: How can you have 2 LARGE_INTEGER? Usually (link in the question) you have only one as input and want to convert it to long long or anything.

Comment: @Sandburg LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
frequency.QuadPart = 0;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency); Do_Something_Worth_Timing(); QueryPerformanceCounter(&t2);
TRACE("It took %f seconds!\n", (float)(t2.QuadPart - t1.QuadPart) / (float)frequency.QuadPart );
LARGE_INTEGER t1, t2;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1); // Assuming the (float) is precise enough...

Answer (score 10):

`LARGE_INTEGER` is a union, [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-large_integer-r1). You probably want a `QuadPart` member.

Answer (score 9):

Here it is:

```
LARGE_INTEGER x,y;
///
//Some codes...
///

__int64 diff = x.QuadPart - y.QuadPart
```

Because **QuadPart** is defined as a **LONGLONG** , that same as **__int64**.

Answer (score 3):

[LARGE_INTEGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383713%28VS.85%29.aspx) is a union, you can still use .QuadPart if you want to work on the 64-bit value.

Answer (score 1):

As the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383713(v=vs.85).aspx) says in the **Remarks** section :

The `LARGE_INTEGER` structure is actually a union. If your compiler has built-in support for 64-bit integers, use the QuadPart member to store the 64-bit integer. Otherwise, use the LowPart and HighPart members to store the 64-bit integer.

So if your compiler supports 64 bit integers use quadPart like this :

```
LARGE_INTEGER a, b;
__int64 diff = a.QuadPart - b.QuadPart
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers, if you are looking to construct a LARGE_INTEGER with a value other than zero, you can assign the low and high parts separately.  LowPart is first as defined in the union, and the only highPart is signed.

```
LARGE_INTEGER li = {0x01234567, -1};
```