# Problems with GetSystemTimes()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cpu, cpu-usage

I'm currently working on a kind of surveillance tool. It's basically like the taskmanager, and I'm just doing this because I want to get in touch with C++ and learn new stuff.

The core of the CPU-usage part is [GetSystemTimes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724400(v=vs.85).aspx). This function returns the pointers to 3 values, the time the CPU has been idle, the time the CPU has been in kernel mode, and the time the CPU has been in user mode. I call the function twice with 250ms sleep in between, and calculate the percentage with the differences of the values.

I have two problems, though. The function returns pointers to FILETIME structures, but I need the actual value as an integer, float, double, or similar, because I need to calculate *(int would be enough for me, but I don't know how large the values are)*. I know that a pointer tells me where the data is saved, but I don't know how I can actually get that data. And how can I get from FILETIME to something else, once I've got it.

```
#include <iostream>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0602
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Processor{};

class Usage: public Processor
{
    public:

    int now()
    {
        FILETIME a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2;

        GetSystemTimes(&a0, &a1, &a2);
        SleepEx(250, false);
        GetSystemTimes(&b0, &b1, &b2);

        // attempt to get the actual value instead of the pointer and convert it to float/double/int
        float idle0 = a0;
        float idle1 = b0;
        float kernel0 = a1;
        float kernel1 = b1;
        float user0 = a2;
        float user1 = b2;

        float idl = idle1 - idle0;
        float ker = kernel0 - kernel1;
        float usr = user0 - user1;

        float cpu = (ker - idl + usr) * 100 / (ker + usr);

        return cpu;
    }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    Usage Usage;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "CPU:\t" << Usage.now() << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nFinished!\nPress any key to exit!\n";
    cin.clear();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of [FILETIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? It's literally the first line in `Remarks` section.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: The [FILETIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284.aspx) structure is already the appropriate type for performing calculations. Converting it to a [SYSTEMTIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950.aspx) structure (as you propose) may be more human-readable, but can no longer be (directly) used in integer or floatingpoint arithmetic.

Comment: It's the second paragraph that matters

Answer (score 4):

Your question can be composed into two easy problems:

1. Convert a `FILETIME` object to an integer value.
2. Calculate the percentage using the integer values previously deduced.

A [FILETIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284.aspx) structure...

> [c]ontains a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

A suitable integer type to store a `FILETIME`'s timestamp is a [uint64_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). The following code performs the conversion:

```
#include <cstdint>

uint64_t FromFileTime( const FILETIME& ft ) {
    ULARGE_INTEGER uli = { 0 };
    uli.LowPart = ft.dwLowDateTime;
    uli.HighPart = ft.dwHighDateTime;
    return uli.QuadPart;
}
```

With this utility function you can change the remaining code to produce the percentage you are looking for:

```
int now() {
    FILETIME a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2;

    GetSystemTimes(&a0, &a1, &a2);
    SleepEx(250, false);
    GetSystemTimes(&b0, &b1, &b2);

    uint64_t idle0 = FromFileTime( a0 );
    uint64_t idle1 = FromFileTime( b0 );
    uint64_t kernel0 = FromFileTime( a1 );
    uint64_t kernel1 = FromFileTime( b1 );
    uint64_t user0 = FromFileTime( a2 );
    uint64_t user1 = FromFileTime( b2 );

    uint64_t idl = idle1 - idle0;
    uint64_t ker = kernel1 - kernel0;
    uint64_t usr = user1 - user0;

    uint64_t cpu = (ker + usr) * 100 / (ker + usr + idl);

    return static_cast<int>( cpu );
}
```

In theory, the multiplication and addition (`ker + usr` or `ker + usr + idl`) can overflow. Technically, those errors should be handled. In reality, however, the values should be very small compared to the maximum value the integer types can store.

Answer (score 0):

Two points, first you say "The function returns pointers to FILETIME structures" - the function returns a BOOL which you have not checked. Second, It takes pointers to `FILETIME` structs as parameters. You have given it the address of local variables - which is fine.
If you have pointers e.g. `FILETIME *pa0` you can deference them to find the members variables etc using `->` e.g. `pa0->dwHighDateTime` 
For your variables `a0`, `a1` etc a simple `.` will suffice.
Notice the type of the two members of a `FILETIME`are actually `DWORD`s so you can use DWORD instead of float to get what you want:

```
        DWORD idle0 = a0.dwHighDateTime;
        DWORD idle1 = b0.dwHighDateTime;
        DWORD kernel0 = a1.dwHighDateTime;
        DWORD kernel1 = b1.dwHighDateTime;
        DWORD user0 = a2.dwHighDateTime;
        DWORD user1 = b2.dwLowDateTime;
```

The API you have linked to has a *suggestion* of how to use a `FILETIME time` to get milliseconds:

```
((ulong)time.dwHighDateTime << 32) + (uint)time.dwLowDateTime)
```

In essence, the two parts give you the whole number you are after. As people said in the comments, the `FILETIME` docs suggest various ways of doing the sums you want.

*BUT* to spell it out in full, you need to be careful with a large integer. (See comment below). The simplest thing to do, is to use a `ULARGE_INTEGER` (a 64-bit value) which has a `LowPart` you can use for the `dwLowDateTime` and `HighPart` you can us for the `dwHighDateTime` then use the QuadPart.

For example see 
[manipulating LARGE_INTEGERS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395361/manipulating-large-integers)

Comment: That final line of code is wrong (and it's not part of the official documentation either). It assumes C#, where `ulong` is a 64-bit unsigned integer value. On Windows, an `unsigned long` however is 32 bits only. I'd recommend using a [ULARGE_INTEGER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383742.aspx) to convert between the `DWORD` pairs and a sufficiently large integer type.

Comment: Fair point - I left off where I was going when people started adding comments

Comment: The [`FILETIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284.aspx) documentation says: "*It is not recommended that you add and subtract values from the FILETIME structure to obtain relative times. Instead, you should copy the low- and high-order parts of the file time to a ULARGE_INTEGER structure, perform 64-bit arithmetic on the QuadPart member, and copy the LowPart and HighPart members into the FILETIME structure. Do not cast a pointer to a FILETIME structure to either a ULARGE_INTEGER* or __int64* value because it can cause alignment faults on 64-bit Windows.*"

Comment: It does. Perhaps it would be better if I removed the addition and bit-shift line of code. I put it there to point out there were clues in the docs the OP linked. I will spell it out in full.